# SSRS - check if some id is more than 1

Tags: sql, reporting-services

i've ID_NOVEO/MKP_Number - MKP_Customer - DoubleCheck

in SSRS i whant the last column is calculated value.
I wanna check if ID_NOVEO is more than 1.

[image: calculated field]

Than it put 1 in "DoubleCheck" field.

Thanks

PS: in sql is this: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a group on ID_Noveo, which you can make hidden.

On the detail your expression should look like the one below

```
= Iif(CountRows("table1_YourGroupName")>1,1,0)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just do this in SQL and pass the results to the report. Something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ID_NOVEO, MKP_CustomerKey
    , CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ID_NOVEO) >1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MoreThanOne 
    FROM YourTable
```